# Saber el valor maximo sin MAX, ORDER BY y LIMIT - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

**Me piden esto**:

> Devuelve el pedido más caro que existe en la tabla pedido sin hacer uso de:
>
> ***`MAX`***, ***`ORDER BY`*** ni ***`LIMIT`***.

¿Hay alguna opción?

En la tabla pedido tengo estos campos:

```
id,
total (precio del pedido),
fecha,
id_cliente fk,
id_comercial fk
```

Comment: Tenes que usar algún lenguaje de programación para conectarte a la base de datos? O estas viendo funciones / procedimentos almacenados?

Comment: No, por ahora no lo tengo que conectar a ningún lenguaje. Son practicas de funcionamiento. Pero solo se me viene a la cabeza MAX o ORDER BY con LIMIT y no puedo usar ninguno de los dos casos

Comment: La verdad.. no se me ocurre como se pude hacer sin recorrer un cursor. Y para eso necesitas hacer una función almacenada.

Answer (score 2):

Se me ocurre usar **`MIN(-total)`**, asumiendo que todos los precios son positivos.

```
SELECT * 
FROM pedido a
INNER JOIN (SELECT min(-1*precio) as precio_maximo 
       FROM pedido) as b
ON a.precio = b.precio_maximo
```

La otra solución que se me ocurre es utilizar:

```
row_number() over(order by precio desc) as n where n = 1
```

Pero esto incluye la cláusula ***order by*** por lo que estrictamente no cumple con el enunciado.

Answer (score 1):

La solución más sencilla que se me ocurre con las restricciones de ***`MAX`***, ***`ORDER BY`*** y ***`LIMIT`*** sería esta:

```
SELECT * FROM pedido a WHERE a.total >= ALL(SELECT b.total FROM pedido b);
```

Es una consulta muy ineficiente, ya que compara todas las filas entre sí, pero válida como respuesta a la pregunta.

Comment: Buena respuesta, adjunto un fiddle porque estaba esceptico pero si funciona http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/92ebcd/2